# Android specific UI

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

I would like to make a system of page on android 3.0 a little bit special.
Here is a plan of the management of the pages that I would like to have:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/814/schemau.jpg/

It would be a question of making as for the management of the notification on the desktop.
I thought of the slideDraw but at the moment it is little decisive.

Have you an idea of which component to use and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FrameLayout` and simple `View Animation`, this is what comes to my mind. Place three layouts on top of each other using `FrameLayout`, then animate them as you like on touch event. Hope this helps.